# Does anyone know this boogie-woogie?

Tags: identify-this-song, blues

have someone ever heard this song? I recorded from the tv. This is the only part i've got:
http://collerblade.pe.hu/short_blues.mp3

Comment: That's not Boogie Woogie, that's rock & roll!!!!

Comment: what program did it come from ?

Answer (score 1):

This is Stevie Ray Vaughan & Double Trouble's "[The House Is Rockin'](https://youtu.be/-G84P5K-W1c)".